# Arrayformula with iferror and vlookup does not update automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

My spreadsheet is for inventory checking. I use several of arrayformula ,iferror and vlookup. 
The problem is I just noticed that sometimes the formula does not update. It might because I duplicated the google sheet to a new one to make it work for another month. 
Here is my formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(vlookup(A3:A,'21'!A:B,2,0)))
```

When it is not updated, it make the entire column blank. And make my inventory count gone wrong. I can make it update by manually goes to the cell and press enter. But that not what I want to do. There are like 100 cells that I have to go through.

And the spreadsheet setting to make it update every minute does not solve this problem.

Comment: Hi. I've just done a quick test of your formula (including  sheet='21'), and also duplicating the sheet containing the formula: it all works fine - immediate update, no failure to update. You mentioned _It might because I duplicated the google sheet to a new one to make it work for another month._ Would you please explain what effect this has on your formula. Would you please describe how many rows of data you are searching &/or the size of this spreadsheet and the recalculation time. You might also share a spreadsheet. Otherwise, without more information, we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've had similar issues with ARRAYFORMULA VLOOKUP. I have other sheets that gets updated with new data and those VLOOKUP should update those new cells but it isn't. Elsewhere, some have suggested a Find and Replace for "=" but that doesn't seem to work.